# Is there any Reference of Wordpress hook and hacks?

Tags: hooks, hacks

I am searching for a website to have lots of Wordpress hacks and hooks.

Some hooks like activating debug mode or etc.

Can you give me lots of this futures ?

Comment: read the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/

Comment: @RRikesh i know that, i need a website to list codes !

Comment: Please have a look at the [Help Center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) on how to ask questions, and what the scope of this community is.

Comment: Just google what you want, yes, there are lists.

Answer (score 2):

Check this page out, http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

It contains links to

1. Actions (Codex [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference))
2. Filters (Codex [Filter Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference))

Also check Adam Brown's [WordPress Hooks Database](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks),